# Database Name as Variable -Dynamic SQL inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, variables, dynamic

I'm having a hard time to solve this issue. My project requirement need to be able to use database name as a parameter. I thought it will be easy since in a stored procedure, we can use it like `[dbname].[dbo].tblname`. But when I replace the dbname with variable, it's not working.

So after sometime googling, I decided to go with dynamic SQL in the stored procedure. But, currently I'm having a hard time to debug this part. On my program it raise a syntax error. I'm hoping if someone could give me a hint, or a better idea for my project. Thanks in advance!

```
  SELECT @DBName=DBName FROM Client WHERE ClientCode = @ClientCode

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + 
       N'.[dbo].Users AS A INNER JOIN'+ @DBName  + 
       N'.[dbo].UserRoles AS B On B.RoleCode = A.UserRole INNER JOIN ' + @DBName + 
       N'.[dbo].Branch AS C On C.BranchCode = A.BranchCode WHERE Username= ' + @UserName + 
       N' AND Password = ' + @Password 

  Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
  Set @ParamDefinition =      N'   @ClientCode VARCHAR(20),' +
                              N' @UserName Varchar(15),' +
                              N' @Password NVARCHAR(200)' 

   exec sp_executesql @SQL,@ParamDefinition
```

Comment: rather than execing, print the sql, take the printed sql, parse it, if no errors, run it.  It will give you a better idea of where to start.

Comment: Start with something simpler such as `'@sql = select count(*) records from ' + @DBName + 'dbo.users where 1=2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use QUOTENAME in your dynamic SQL, this is very important to prevent SQL Injection
- username and password *can* and *should* stay parameters
- pass in the declared parameters

So like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + 
       N'.[dbo].Users AS A INNER JOIN '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName)  +  
       N'.[dbo].UserRoles AS B On B.RoleCode = A.UserRole INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + 
       N'.[dbo].Branch AS C On C.BranchCode = A.BranchCode WHERE Username= @UserName AND Password = @Password'

   exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@UserName VARCHAR(15), @Password NVARCHAR(200)', @UserName, @Password
```

Finally: never store passwords in the database. Use instead a [salted hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure).

Comment: it works..this is the most complete answers.and thanks for the tips =)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space on the second line of your dynamic SQL generation.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + 
   N'.[dbo].Users AS A INNER JOIN ' + @DBName  + -- space added
   N'.[dbo].UserRoles AS B On B.RoleCode = A.UserRole INNER JOIN ' + @DBName + 
   N'.[dbo].Branch AS C On C.BranchCode = A.BranchCode WHERE Username= ' + @UserName + 
   N' AND Password = ' + @Password
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite like this so is easy to read

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + 
   @DBName + N'.[dbo].Users AS A INNER JOIN ' + 
                                          ^^^ space add here 
   @DBName + N'.[dbo].UserRoles AS B On B.RoleCode = A.UserRole INNER JOIN ' +
   @DBName + N'.[dbo].Branch AS C On C.BranchCode = A.BranchCode ' + 
   N' WHERE Username= ' + @UserName + 
   N' AND Password = ' + @Password
```

and like Joe R say, was a missing space.